# Failing to store result in variable after jq filter

Tags: json, bash, jq

```
url="http://something.com"
data=`curl -sb -H  $url`
result=$($data | jq --arg Name "$1" -r '.items[] | select(.app==$Name) | .name')
echo $result
```

I am not able to store result

Answer (score 1):

The shell will try to execute the contents of `$data`.  Try this:

```
result=$(echo $data | jq --arg Name "$1" -r '.items[] | select(.app==$Name) | .name')
```

Or my preference:

```
result=$( curl -sb -H $url |  jq --arg Name "$1" -r '.items[] | select(.app==$Name) | .name')
```